# CSV file reading index with symbols

Tags: python, csv, symbols

I'm reading a CSV file, the first "column" it's ID, but python is bringing 'ï»¿Id' instead of Id

```
df_mk = pd.read_csv(dl_path + "\\" + filename, encoding='latin-1')
```

can't make it read it as Id

Comment: You say the encoding of the file is Latin-1, but is it really? Aren't you simply reading a UTF file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your encoding is wrong?

utf-8 is more common than latin-1

Comment: More of a comment than an answer?

Comment: Ok I'm pretty new. Am I supposed to delete this answer then?